# $top and $skip parameter to obtain places instead of @odata.nextLink

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How do I use $top and $skip parameter to obtain users?

On running https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$count=true I see @odata.nextLink is missing in the response. Is there a way to use $top and $skip parameters to retrieve the remaining results?

[image]

UPDATE:

```
var top = 100;
var skip = 0;
var total = response.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.count", out object count) ? (int)count : 0;
if (total > 0)
{               
    var numberOfRequests = (int)Math.Ceiling(total / 100);
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfRequests; i++)
    {
        skip += top;
        var response = await GetPlacesAsync(url, 100, skip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$top` and `$skip` parameters are supported.

return first 5 rooms

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=5

var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
var response= await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, null)
                          .Top(5).GetAsync();
```

return next 5 rooms

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$top=5&$skip=5

var roomUrl = graphClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
            var response= await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphClient, null)
                          .Top(5).Skip(5).GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give sample C# code as well for the same?

Comment: Thank you! Let’s say I have 200 rooms in response. Should I run .Top(5).Skip(5) multiple times? How do I know I reached last set rooms from the response?

Comment: If you know the exact number then you calculate how many times you need to call the query and increment number for skip parameter. Second option is that the response will be empty. For 200 rooms .Top(5).Skip(200) will return empty collection.

Comment: please see the image in my question. How do I get 207 results?

Comment: Request1 - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$count=true&$top=100&$skip=100 Request2 - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$count=true&$top=100&$skip=100 Request3 - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room?$count=true&$top=100&$skip=200

Comment: does this look correct